# How to invisibly return a portion of a list

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I might be missing something very simple here.

How do I create a user-defined function in R that returns a list where some elements are invisible?

```
sky <- function(){
list(sun = 1, clouds = 4, birds =2, moon = 0)
}

up <- sky()

up
#$sun
#[1] 1
#
#$clouds
#[1] 4
#
#$birds
#[1] 2
#
#$moon
#[1] 0
```

I would like `up` to print `up$sun` and `up$clouds` but not the other two elements.  Yet, I still want `up` to be a list of all four elements:

```
names(up)
#[1] "sun"    "clouds" "birds"  "moon"
```

Comment: You are asking for a "call" to `up` which means it's a function but then you are asking for it to display names as though its a data-object.

Comment: Good point. I just corrected this.

Comment: What does an element being "invisible" mean? What would `up$birds` return?

Comment: `up$birds` returns 2.  But when you print `up`, `up$birds` and `up$moon` are not listed.  As another example, if `a` is of class `"lm"`, then `print(summary(a))` returns an incomplete list of the elements in `names(summary(a))`.  How is that done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make an S3 print method

```
sky <- function(){
  structure(list(sun = 1, clouds = 4, birds =2, moon = 0), class="mysky")
}
print.mysky <- function(x, ...) print(x[1:2])

sky()
#$sun
#[1] 1
#
#$clouds
#[1] 4
```

You can see that that only affects how it is printed

```
str(sky())
#List of 4
# $ sun   : num 1
# $ clouds: num 4
# $ birds : num 2
# $ moon  : num 0
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "mysky"

names(sky())
#[1] "sun"    "clouds" "birds"  "moon"
```

---

Here's another way to assign a class to an object

```
sky <- function(){
  out <- list(sun = 1, clouds = 4, birds =2, moon = 0)
  class(out) <- "mysky"
  out
}
```

`print.mysky` will be dispatched since the object's class is "mysky"

```
class(sky())
#[1] "mysky"
```

---

if you want to dispatch the default print method you can either call it directly (`print.default(sky())`), or `unclass` the object

```
#print.default(sky())
unclass(sky())

#$sun
#[1] 1
#
#$clouds
#[1] 4
#
#$birds
#[1] 2
#
#$moon
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `print` to do the work. It does have an advantage over `cat` that it "understands" lists:

```
 sky <- function(){
    x <- list(sun = 1, clouds = 4, birds =2, moon = 0)
    print(x[1:2])
    invisible(x)
 }
#----------- 
> up <- sky()
$sun
[1] 1

$clouds
[1] 4

> z <- sky()
$sun
[1] 1

$clouds
[1] 4

> print(z)
$sun
[1] 1

$clouds
[1] 4

$birds
[1] 2

$moon
[1] 0
```

Often one uses `cat` if the goal is putting something out tot hte console that is not a value

```
sky <- function(){
x <- list(sun = 1, clouds = 4, birds =2, moon = 0)
sapply(x[1:2], cat, "\n")
invisible(x)
}

up <- sky()
1
4
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you do this with JQuery. Put the elements in `<li>` and use JQuery to hide and show elements. You may show the First two, or show all the rest. I hope this mechanism works for you.

```
<ul class="collapse">
     <li>sun</li>
     <li>clouds</li>
     <li>birds</li>
     <li>moon</li>
</ul>
```

the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('ul.collapse').wrap('<div class="collapseWrapper" />');
     $('div.collapseWrapper').css({ 'height' : '45px' }).after('<a href="#" class="collapseMore">view details . . .</a>');

     $('a.collapseMore').click(function () {
          if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
               $(this).prev().animate({ height: '45px' }, 500);
               $(this).text('view details . . .').removeClass('expanded');
          }
          else {
               $(this).prev().animate({ height: $(this).prev().find( 'ul.collapse' ).outerHeight(true) }, 500);
               $(this).text('hide details . . .').addClass('expanded');
          }
          return false;
     });
});
```

the CSS:

```
ul.collapse{  }
ul.collapse li {  }
div.collapseWrapper { overflow: hidden; }
a.collapseMore {  }
a.collapseMore:hover {  }
```